# pdf-tools: set a number of colors readily available for highlighting

Tags: customize, highlighting, pdf-tools

When reading a pdf file, I use different colors for highlighting; for example to distinguish different ideas.

Is it possible to have a number of colors readily available when using pdf-tools. That is after highlighting,  *right-click > change color*

Comment: It is. Every time you choose another color, it will get added to the 'readily available colors' (the listed colors after navigating to `change-color`). Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, it does not answer the question because that way the colors for highlighting have to be selected every time you open emacs and that is what I would like to avoid

Comment: A yes... I see. Well, it looks like @whitetrillium already posted a nice solution indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set your preferred colours

```lisp
(setq pdf-annot-color-history '("red" "yellow" "blue"))
```

2. While viewing the  `pdf` file, do `M-x pdf-annot-minor-mode`
3. Do `C-c C-a m`, which is same as `M-x pdf-annot-add-markup-annotation`

   - press `ENTER`.

     This chooses `highlight` as your choice. You will be prompted for a color with `Color (default red)`.
   - Now, ***keep on pressing*** `M-p` (`previous-history-element`) until you see the color you want.

     Press `ENTER` to choose the color

With regard to choosing among "historical candidates", it is convenient to go with some completion framework.

- If you are using `helm`, when prompted for a color, do `M-x helm-minibuffer-history` and select from the pre-configured colors.

I am using `M-g M-h` for `helm-minibuffer-history`.  This is my own custom binding.

Here is a screenshot of what I see when I do `C-c C-a m RET M-g M-h RET`,

[image: Choose color for PDF annotation using helm]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. `(setq pdf-annot-color-history '("red" "yellow" "blue"))` is what I was looking for